# find first level children in nokogiri rails

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I've faced with a problem how to find first level children from the current element ?
For example i have html :

```html
 <table>
   <tr>abc</tr>
   <tr>def</tr>   
   <table>
     <tr>second</tr>
   </table>
 </table>
```

I am using Nokogiri for rails :

```
table = page.css('table')
table.css('tr')
```

It returns all `tr` inside `table`.
But I need only 2 that first level for the table.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you say this:

```
table = page.css('table')
```

you're grabbing both tables rather than just the top level table. So you can either go back to the document root and use a selector that only matches the rows in the first table as mosch says or you can fix `table` to be only the outer table with something like this:

```
table = page.css('table').first
trs   = table.xpath('./tr')
```

or even this (depending on the HTML's real structure):

```
table = page.xpath('/html/body/table')
trs   = table.xpath('./tr')
```

or perhaps one of these for `table` (thanks Phrogz, again):

```
table = page.at('table')
table = page.at_css('table')
# or various other CSS and XPath incantations
```

Comment: You might want to mention `page.at('table')` or `page.at_css('table')` instead of `page.css('table').first`.

Comment: @Phrogz: Thanks, I threw those in the mix too.

Comment: At the risk of taking it too far: page.xpath('//table[not(ancestor::*[1][name()="table"])]')

Comment: @pguardiario: I was waiting for something like that to happen, I just didn't want to be responsible for it :) You could throw that down as an answer (after adding the trailing `/tr`, `page.xpath('//table[not(ancestor::*[1][name()="table"])]/tr')`), a bit of XPath never hurt anyone.

Answer (score 6):

You can do

```
rows = page.css('body > table > tr')
```

Perhaps you have to adapt the selector to your container element (i chose 'body' here)

Comment: No, because it this case you also selected tr element nested in inner table

Comment: You can also do `table.css('> tr')` to get the direct descendent of the table

Answer (score 1):

As yet another way, you can try to use something like this:

```
text = <<HERE
  <table>
    <tr>abc</tr>
    <tr>def</tr>   
    <table>
      <tr>second</tr>
    </table>
  </table>
HERE
xml = Nokogiri::XML(text)
xml.xpath("/table/tr/").each do |node|
  puts node.text
end
```

In this example, '/table/tr' expression represents an absolute path to the required element - 'tr' in our case.

Comment: since this is html, you really want to use Nokogiri::HTML. Also the trailing slash in your xpath breaks it.

Comment: Oops, these are a couple my typos - you're perfectly right, my apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

[xpath did not work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690737/nokogiri-xpath-namespace-query)

The below code worked fine for me.

```
table = page.css('table')
table.css('> tr')
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this?

```
tables = doc.css('table')

tables.each do |table|
  rows = table.css('tr')

  rows.each do |row|
    if row.parent == table
      # Some action here...
    end
  end
end
```