# Displaying XML nodes with Nokogiri in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, xslt, nokogiri

So using the advice found in my previous '[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017667/using-nokogiri-to-search-through-xml-file-based-on-user-input-in-rails-app)', I have been able to get the results I want.

I was wondering if anyone had an easy way to display these results in a Rails view that also has non XML content.

I've looked into XSLT but don't know enough about it, especially not in relation to Rails, to know whether that is where I should spend my time. If so, I'd love some pointers on how I can use XSLT in Rails views.

What I am looking for is to display a list of 'sdnEntry' results (see '[XML Schema](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/SDN-List/Documents/sdn.xsd)' for details.)

As you will see from the '[XML Schema](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/SDN-List/Documents/sdn.xsd)', not all of the 'sdnEntry' items have the same  elements.  Therefore, I'd like to display the following information about each 'sdnEntry', omitting any empty elements where applicable.

Please feel free to ask questions in comments. I really appreciate the help.

EDIT #1: The XML file can be found [here](http://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.xml). (6MB)

EDIT #2: I'd prefer something like a `<dl>/<dt><dd>` list. Heck, I'd even settle for a plain old table. As for empty elements, you will see from the schema, that some child elements (like 'firstName' or 'address3', etc.) have 0 minimum occurrences, and are therefore not found for every 'sdnEntry'. If possible, I'd rather not show blank child elements. If that's a problem, I'd be fine with blanks in the end, if needed.

EDIT #3: The results will always be a Nokogiri NodeSet of one or more 'sdnEntry' items. That's all I would need to display. I am confident that with enough guidance or example code, I could apply any provided solution to other needs down the line.

Comment: When you say "display these results in a Rails view" do you mean that you want to display the raw XML in a 'pretty' format, like [this image](http://www.kirupa.com/net/images/xml_doc2.gif)? If so, is syntax coloring important? Or did you mean that you want to extract the information from the XML and display it in a pretty format (e.g. as a `<dl>/<dt><dd>` list custom labeled and formatted)? If so, did you need a generic solution (any XML snippet) or something tailored to the specific results you are getting?

Comment: I don't know what you mean in your next-to-last paragraph, _"I'd like to display the following information about each 'sdnEntry'"_. Did you intend to provide a list of specific elements you wanted to display? Or were you saying that even if there is no particular child element (e.g. if `<firstName>` is legally omitted) you still want to include an empty element in the output?

Comment: You forgot to provide the wanted output (I hope the XML document is somewhwere pointed to by the provided links).

Comment: Provided responses in the edits above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still haven't given enough details about what you actually want for me to give you a good answer, but you've given just enough to get *an* answer. :p

The following shows how to load your XML file into a Nokogiri document, create a Haml template (which would be part of your Rails view; if you're using Erb or some other template system, say so) that runs through a list of `sdnEntry` and performs a completely naive huge dump of all the XML. If you want specific nodes, then you should have said so.

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
require 'haml'

# Haml helper to create a naive hierarchy of dl/dt/dd for any xml node
def xml_to_dl(node)
  haml_tag('dl') do
    node.elements.each do |n|
      haml_tag('dt',n.name)
      if n.elements.empty?
        haml_tag('dd',n.text)
      else
        haml_tag('dd'){ xml_to_dl(n) }
      end
    end
  end
end

# This would be your page.haml view
template = Haml::Engine.new <<'ENDHAML'
%section#sdnList
  %h1#sdnList SDN List Awesomeness
  - if @sdns.empty?
    %p.error No entries found. :(
  - else
    %p Here are some exciting sdnEntries. Check em out!
    - @sdns.each do |sdn|
      %h2.name #{sdn.at('lastName').text}, #{sdn.at('firstName').text}
      - xml_to_dl(sdn)
ENDHAML

# This would be in your controller
doc  = Nokogiri.XML(IO.read('sdn.xml'))
doc.remove_namespaces! # Make life easier
@sdns = doc.xpath('/sdnList/sdnEntry[firstName][position() < 2]')

# This is taken care of by rails
puts template.render(self)
```

And here's the output that particular template would create:

```html
<section id='sdnList'>
  <h1 id='sdnList'>SDN List Awesomeness</h1>
  <p>Here are some exciting sdnEntries. Check em out!</p>
  <h2 class='name'>GONZALEZ BOHORQUEZ, Guillermo</h2>
  <dl>
    <dt>uid</dt>
    <dd>11764</dd>
    <dt>firstName</dt>
    <dd>Guillermo</dd>
    <dt>lastName</dt>
    <dd>GONZALEZ BOHORQUEZ</dd>
    <dt>sdnType</dt>
    <dd>Individual</dd>
    <dt>programList</dt>
    <dd>
      <dl>
        <dt>program</dt>
        <dd>SDNT</dd>
      </dl>
    </dd>
    <dt>idList</dt>
    <dd>
      <dl>
        <dt>id</dt>
        <dd>
          <dl>
            <dt>uid</dt>
            <dd>6139</dd>
            <dt>idType</dt>
            <dd>Cedula No.</dd>
            <dt>idNumber</dt>
            <dd>6185654</dd>
            <dt>idCountry</dt>
            <dd>Colombia</dd>
          </dl>
        </dd>
        <dt>id</dt>
        <dd>
          <dl>
            <dt>uid</dt>
            <dd>6140</dd>
            <dt>idType</dt>
            <dd>Passport</dd>
            <dt>idNumber</dt>
            <dd>AJ772175</dd>
            <dt>idCountry</dt>
            <dd>Colombia</dd>
          </dl>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </dd>
    <dt>addressList</dt>
    <dd>
      <dl>
        <dt>address</dt>
        <dd>
          <dl>
            <dt>uid</dt>
            <dd>17790</dd>
            <dt>address1</dt>
            <dd>c/o UNIVISA S.A.</dd>
            <dt>city</dt>
            <dd>Cali</dd>
            <dt>country</dt>
            <dd>Colombia</dd>
          </dl>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </dd>
    <dt>dateOfBirthList</dt>
    <dd>
      <dl>
        <dt>dateOfBirthItem</dt>
        <dd>
          <dl>
            <dt>uid</dt>
            <dd>7272</dd>
            <dt>dateOfBirth</dt>
            <dd>20 Dec 1944</dd>
            <dt>mainEntry</dt>
            <dd>true</dd>
          </dl>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </dd>
    <dt>placeOfBirthList</dt>
    <dd>
      <dl>
        <dt>placeOfBirthItem</dt>
        <dd>
          <dl>
            <dt>uid</dt>
            <dd>7273</dd>
            <dt>placeOfBirth</dt>
            <dd>Buga, Valle, Colombia</dd>
            <dt>mainEntry</dt>
            <dd>true</dd>
          </dl>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</section>
```

Comment: While my lack of knowledge means that I apparently did not ask the question in a way that allowed you to answer the question in a way that you wanted, your answer served my purposes just fine. It gave me enough information to sort out the rest. And for that, I thank you.