# xpath attribute of root node

Tags: xml, xpath, nokogiri

I wan to fetch the ID, LASTEDITED, EXPIRESS attributes in the root element. I am using xpath, ruby and nokogiri. But it dosent work, any ideas?

xPath querys:

```
  doc.xpath('/educationProvider/@id').each do |id_node| 
    puts node.content
  end

  doc.xpath('/educationProvider/@lastEdited').each do |lastedited_node|
    puts lastedited_node.content
  end

  doc.xpath('/educationProvider/@expires').each do |expires_node|
    puts expires_node.content
  end
```

This how my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:educationProvider xmlns:p="http://skolverket.se/education/provider/1.0" xmlns="http://skolverket.se/education/commontypes/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" expires="2015-01-31" id="provider.uh.msb" lastEdited="2012-11-01T12:51:37" xsi:schemaLocation="http://skolverket.se/education/provider/1.0 educationProvider.xsd">
        <p:vCard>
            <VERSION/> 
            <FN/> 
            <N/> 
            <ADR>
                <LOCALITY>KARLSTAD</LOCALITY> 
                <PCODE>651 81</PCODE> 
            </ADR>
            <TEL>
                <NUMBER>0771-240240</NUMBER> 
            </TEL>
            <EMAIL>
                <USERID>utbildning@msbmyndigheten.se</USERID> 
            </EMAIL>
            <ORG>
                <ORGNAME>Myndigheten för samhällsskydd och beredskap</ORGNAME> 
            </ORG>
            <URL>http://www.msbmyndigheten.se</URL>
        </p:vCard>
    </p:educationProvider>
```

HERE IS MY RUBY-SCRIPT:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# parse the HTML document with all the links to the XML files.
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://testnavet.skolverket.se/SusaNavExport/EmilExporter?GetEvent&EMILVersion=1.1&NotExpired&EIAcademicType=UoH&SelectEP'))
# URLS - array
@urls = Array.new 
#Get all XML-urls and save them in urls-array
doc.xpath('//a/@href').each do |links|
  @urls << links.content
end

@id = Array.new
@lastedited = Array.new
@expires = Array.new

# loop all the url of the XML files
@urls.each do |url|
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  # grab the content I want
  doc.xpath('/educationProvider/@id').each do |id_node| 
    id_node.content
  end

  doc.xpath('/educationProvider/@lastEdited').each do |lastedited_node|
    @lastedited << lastedited_node.content
  end

  doc.xpath('/educationProvider/@expires').each do |expires_node|
    @expires << expires_node.content
  end
end

#print it out
(0..@id.length - 1).each do |index|
  puts "ID: #{@id[index]}"
  puts "Lastedited: #{@lastedited[index]}"
  puts "Expiress: #{@expires[index]}"
end
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690737/nokogiri-xpath-namespace-query

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I wan to fetch the ID, LASTEDITED, EXPIRESS attributes in the root
>   element.

**Just use**:

```
/*/@id
```

This selects the `id` attribute of the top element of the XML document.

```
/*/@lastEdited
```

This selects the `lastEdited` attribute of the top element of the XML document.

```
/*/@expires
```

This selects the `expires` attribute of the top element of the XML document.

**Alternatively, all these three attributes can be selected with a single XPath expression**:

```
/*/@*[contains('|id|lastEdited|expires|', 
               concat('|', name(), '|')
               )
     ]
```

**XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select=
  "/*/@*[contains('|id|lastEdited|expires|',
                  concat('|', name(), '|')
                  )
         ]">
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat('&#xA;',
           name(),
           ' = ',
           .
          )"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this XSLT transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<p:educationProvider xmlns:p="http://skolverket.se/education/provider/1.0" xmlns="http://skolverket.se/education/commontypes/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" expires="2015-01-31" id="provider.uh.msb" lastEdited="2012-11-01T12:51:37" xsi:schemaLocation="http://skolverket.se/education/provider/1.0 educationProvider.xsd">
    <p:vCard>
        <VERSION/>
        <FN/>
        <N/>
        <ADR>
            <LOCALITY>KARLSTAD</LOCALITY>
            <PCODE>651 81</PCODE>
        </ADR>
        <TEL>
            <NUMBER>0771-240240</NUMBER>
        </TEL>
        <EMAIL>
            <USERID>utbildning@msbmyndigheten.se</USERID>
        </EMAIL>
        <ORG>
            <ORGNAME>Myndigheten för samhällsskydd och beredskap</ORGNAME>
        </ORG>
        <URL>http://www.msbmyndigheten.se</URL>
    </p:vCard>
</p:educationProvider>
```

**the Xpath expression is evaluated and for each of the selected attributes their name and value are output**:

```
expires = 2015-01-31
id = provider.uh.msb
lastEdited = 2012-11-01T12:51:37
```

Comment: Great answer, spec the last expression. But I have tried that and it wont print it.. something is fishy..

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake: Uff... I corrected the XPath expression -- try now.

Comment: I am sorry, but where did you change the expression and did you put a extra file somewhere

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake: the ipdated expression is the last expression, that selects all wanted attributes. In it it was necessary to change `.` to `name()`. As for "updated ruby-script", no, I can't provide such as I am not a Ruby programmer. This answer is a pure XPath one. When the Ruby program evaluates this XPath expression, it will have the list (sequence/array) of selected nodes (objects). Then it depends on your requirements how to process these.

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake: This is not a "script" but XSLT transformation. It is run using an XSLT processor (I am using a dozen of different XSLT processors on a daily basis). Almost any XSLT processor has a command-line utility (such as msxsl.exe for MSXML, nxslt.exe for .NET XslCompiledTransform, etc...). A transformation can also be more conveniently developed and executed/debugged with an IDE, such as the XSeleretor (which I am using), oXygen or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the root node in the document, you can do this:

```
root = doc.root
root_id = root['id']
last_edited = root['lastEdited']
```

If you need to find it with XPath, you need to use the correct namespace.  Your root node has a namespace of "p", so you must do this:

```
doc.xpath('/p:educationProvider/@id').first.value
```

Notice the `p:` that is preceding your node name.

Comment: I removed p: becuase I get a syntaxerror: undefined namespace prefix. Have you tried my script? does it work for you, and if does can plzz provid it for my. This script is apart of a bigger one.. I would be so happy, beacuse this is killing me.

Comment: And I need to loop it, beacuse I am grapping 4000 other XML files with the same XML structure.