# XML Namespace issue with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have the following XML:

```
<body>
  <hello xmlns='http://...'>
     <world>yes</world>
  </hello>
</body>
```

When I load that into a Nokogiri XML document, and call `document.at_css "world"`, I receive `nil` back. But when I remove the namespace for `hello`, it works perfectly. I know I can call `document.remove_namespaces!`, but why is it that it will not work with the namespace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nokogiri/Xpath namespace query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690737/nokogiri-xpath-namespace-query)

Comment: This refers to `css`, not `xpath`.

Comment: The namespace technique is identical. It doesn't matter if your query is CSS or XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Nokogiri requires you to register the XML namespaces you are querying within (read more about [XML Namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace)). But you should still be able to query the element if you specify its namespace when calling `at_css`. To see the exact usage, check out the [`css` method documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css). It should end up looking something like this:

```
document.at_css "world", 'namespace_name' => 'namespace URI'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that example. What you have didn't work, but it worked when I included the namespace pipe: `document.at_css 'ns|world', 'ns' => 'namespace URI`

Comment: Worth noting is that if there is a namespace declared on the root element, then the `#at_css` or `#css` methods will implicitly include the namespace in the query.