# Can't address XML attribute thought XPath in Ruby (using Nokogiri)

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to filter xml file to get nodes with certain attribute. I can successfully filter by node (ex. \top_manager), but when I try \\top_manager[@salary='great'] I get nothing.

```
    <?xml version= "1.0"?>
<employee xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="employee.xsd">
    <top_manager>
        <ceo salary="great" respect="enormous" type="extra">
            <fname>
                Vasya 
            </fname>
            <lname>
                Pypkin
            </lname>
            <hire_date>
                19
            </hire_date>
            <descr>
                Big boss
            </descr>
        </ceo>
        <cio salary="big" respect="great" type="intro">
            <fname>
                Petr
            </fname>
            <lname>
                Pypkin
            </lname>
            <hire_date>
                25
            </hire_date>
            <descr>
                Resposible for information security
            </descr>
        </cio>
    </top_manager>
```

......

How I need to correct this code to get what I need?

```
require 'nokogiri'
f = File.open("employee.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
doc.xpath("//top_manager[@salary='great']").each do |node|
puts node.text
end
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `salary` is not attribute of `<top_manager>` element, it is the attribute of `<top_manager>`'s children elements :

```
//xmlns:top_manager[*[@salary='great']]
```

Above XPath select `<top_manager>` element having any of it's child element has attribute `salary` equals `"great"`. Or if you meant to select the children (the `<ceo>` element in this case) :

```
//xmlns:top_manager/*[@salary='great']
```

Comment: @JohnWalski Any of 2 suggested XPath above return the correct nodes you needed?

Comment: Sorry for delay, troubles with health. I need the second XPath request.I understand my error. But this code don't work for me even with the improvements. My code returns 0. Can you give some advice on this problem?

Comment: @JohnWalski I suspect that's because the XML has default namespace, try to add `xmlns` prefix in the XPath (I'm not ruby user, basing this suggestion from another thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690737/nokogiri-xpath-namespace-query). Answer updated to reflect this suggestion